# Get list of installed software of remote computer

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-debugging, installed-applications

Is it possible to get a list of installed software of a remote computer ?
I know to do this for a local computer with use of Powershell.  Is it possible with Powershell to get installed software of a remote computer and save this list on the remote computer ?
This I use for local computers:
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name

Thanks in advance,
Best regards,

Comment: Yep: [Connecting to WMI on a Remote Computer by Using Windows PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309377(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check computers for installed program in powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406010/check-computers-for-installed-program-in-powershell). There's also http://stackoverflow.com/q/34135657/62576 that contains relevant information. Please do a search here before posting a new question; chances are quite good that the question has been asked (and answered) here before.

Comment: Get-WmiObject –computername mycomputer -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name . I dont think it's a duplicate...but ok , this did the job for me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey to check the SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall registry key on remote computers.

https://github.com/gangstanthony/PowerShell/blob/master/Get-InstalledApps.ps1

*edit: pasting code for reference

```
function Get-InstalledApps {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        [string]$NameRegex = ''
    )
    
    foreach ($comp in $ComputerName) {
        $keys = '','\Wow6432Node'
        foreach ($key in $keys) {
            try {
                $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $comp)
                $apps = $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE$key\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall").GetSubKeyNames()
            } catch {
                continue
            }

            foreach ($app in $apps) {
                $program = $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE$key\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\$app")
                $name = $program.GetValue('DisplayName')
                if ($name -and $name -match $NameRegex) {
                    [pscustomobject]@{
                        ComputerName = $comp
                        DisplayName = $name
                        DisplayVersion = $program.GetValue('DisplayVersion')
                        Publisher = $program.GetValue('Publisher')
                        InstallDate = $program.GetValue('InstallDate')
                        UninstallString = $program.GetValue('UninstallString')
                        Bits = $(if ($key -eq '\Wow6432Node') {'64'} else {'32'})
                        Path = $program.name
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways how to get the list of installed software on a remote computer:

1. Running WMI query on ROOT\CIMV2 namespace:

   - Start WMI Explorer or any other tool which can run WMI queries.
   - Run WMI query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Product"
2. Using wmic command-line interface:

   - Press WIN+R
   - Type "wmic", press Enter
   - In wmic command prompt type "/node:RemoteComputerName product"
3. Using Powershell script:

   - Thru WMI object: Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -Computer RemoteComputerName
   - thru Registry: Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize
   - thru Get-RemoteProgram cmdlet: Get-RemoteProgram -ComputerName RemoteComputerName

Source: https://www.action1.com/kb/list_of_installed_software_on_remote_computer.html

Answer (score 0):

No one seems to know about get-package in powershell 5.1.  You'll have to use invoke-command to run it on a remote computer.

```
get-package | more

Name                           Version          Source                 ProviderName
----                           -------          ------                 ------------
7-Zip 21.07 (x64)              21.07                                   Msi
Wolfram Extras 11.0 (5570611)  11.0.0                                  Programs
ArcGIS Desktop Background G... 10.8.12790                              Programs
# and so on...
```

msi provider uninstall:

```
get-package *chrome* | uninstall-package
```

programs provider uninstall varies:

```
get-package *notepad++* | % { & $_.metadata['uninstallstring'] /S }
```

Comment: There are a multitude of different ways for software to be installed on Windows. Not everything that's installed is visible through WMI, not everything is visible through the PackageManagement module (i.e. Get-Package). It's a mess, so you have to use whichever module(s) works with the software you intend to remove. Here's another reference discussing this (ignore the statement _"(WMI) is the only mechanism mentioned here that can perform this task remotely."_)
[link](https://4sysops.com/archives/uninstall-programs-remotely-with-powershell/)